# Displaying SSAS measure in thousands or millions

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an Olap cube created using Microsoft SSAS.  Inside I have a many-to-many relationship between source transaction currency and required "Reporting" currency.  This is all functional, however to display a dynamic currency symbol I am using the "Currency" format string default and passing in a custom LCID based on the currency selected.

The problem with using the "Currency" format is the decimal places and large numbers.  I am reporting millions of pounds/dollars and my CFO wants to see these numbers reported in thousands or millions.  To control this I have read about using a special format string like `#,,` but this won't allow the currency symbol to be shown.

I had an idea to have a special dimension which would equate to 1, 1000, 1000000 and then create a calculated measure which divides by this (obviously defaulting to 1 and not aggregatable), but I have lots of measures.

Can anybody else advise on an alternative approach?

Comment: What do you use to show a report? Probably you can reuse your front-end tool set.

Comment: Currently using Excel and Pyramid Analytics. Problem with front end tools is they think they know better, when you say make it millions it cuts off the cube format currency symbol leaving the report consumer guessing their currency!

Answer (score 1):

I would just set the `FORMAT_STRING` via a script assignment:

```
FORMAT_STRING(([Dim-Currency].[Currency Code].&[USD])) = "$#,,";
FORMAT_STRING(([Dim-Currency].[Currency Code].&[Euro])) = "€#,,";
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to ask a silly question, but it appears this sets a format string on the dimension, how is this then subsequently applied to many measures?

Comment: @DomCotton test it but I believe it will be applied to all measures. If not we can possible include [Measures].AllMembers in each statement.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the SCOPE statement here:

```
Scope(AddCalculatedMembers([Measures].Members));
    This = case     
        when [Measures].CurrentMember >= 1000000
        then Cstr(Cint([Measures].CurrentMember / 1000000)) + " millions"
        when [Measures].CurrentMember >= 1000
        then Cstr(Cint([Measures].CurrentMember / 1000)) + " thousands"
        else [Measures].CurrentMember
    end;
End Scope;
```

Where **Cint** return int value and **Cstr** helps to join int value to text. I'm not sure if it's not too much. I've never used the "Currency" type, honestly.

Comment: Interesting approach, the issue is totally with the currency symbol.  I currently use this code `Language(([Dim-Currency].[Currency Code].Members,[Measures].[Sales])) = [Dim-Currency].[Currency Code].CurrentMember.MemberValue; ` and in the dimension it has a value for the LCID - this makes the currency symbol dynamic.  I would need to build that into your scope statement but will give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @GregGalloway. In our cube-script it is implemented like this:

```
Scope
([Dim-Currency].[Currency Code].&[EUR]); 
//EUR
    FORMAT_STRING(This) = '€ #,##0.00';  
End Scope; 

Scope
([Dim-Currency].[Currency Code].&[GBP]); 
    FORMAT_STRING(This) = '£ #,##0.00';  
End Scope;
```

We render via Pyramid front-end.